# Difference behavior of replaceAll versus replaceFirst

Tags: java, regex

When I run these tests

```
public class ReplacementTest {

    @Test
    public void testReplaceFirst() {

        Assert.assertEquals("123", "12003".replaceFirst("0*", ""));
    }

    @Test
    public void testReplaceAll() {

        Assert.assertEquals("123", "12003".replaceAll("0*", ""));
    }

}
```

`testReplaceFirst` fails but `testReplaceAll` passes.  Why doesn't `replaceFirst` match on "00" in "12003"?

Comment: Do you know what `*` represents in regex? Hint: execute `"12003".replaceFirst("0*", "X")` and see what is its result.

Comment: Can't you use "00" instead of "0*"? It might fix this error.

Comment: @Pshemo I know that ``*`` means "0 or more".  Why doesn't that match the "00" in "12003"?

Comment: So you must realize that `0*` can also accept string with no zeroes like empty string `""`. How do you think, does such string exist in your input? Hint: what will happen when we execute: `""+"foo"`?

Comment: So it's matching the zero zeroes at the front of the "12003"?

Comment: Just look at [what the regex matches](https://regex101.com/r/lR7bW2/1) - I think you just need to start using online regex testers.

Comment: @Thevenin Precisely.

Comment: @Thevenin your regex beside matching empty string at start of input can even match empty strings between each non-0 characters and at the end of string. Take a look at https://ideone.com/4wxNmJ

Comment: Please don't ask separate question in same post (even if they are related to your problem). This may make already posted answers invalid. If you have new question create new post (after making sure that it is not already being answered on Stack Overflow).

Comment: Anyway answer to your additional question can be found in javadoc of `matches` method. Read it and come back if you will have any questions.

Comment: Never use a regex that states that a match can be nothing. Always set a portion of the regex as something that can be matched.

Comment: Why is your example code doing an Assert?. Why don't you just print out the results and you can see what is happening with different regexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are observing the specifics of `Matcher.find` logic. To understand it execute the next code:

```
"12003".replaceAll("0*", "x");
```

You will see the next output:

```
x1x2xx3x
```

Matcher attempts to find the first place where your pattern occurs in the target string. Considering that zero match is also a match (according to your pattern), it matches the specific region before the `1`. And while `replaceAll` will continue the job with next regions, `replaceFirst` will not.